# combine multiple similar AJAX codes

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, simplify

I have the below code that goes with my site navigation. Since most of the code is the same I was wondering if there was a way to condense this. I'm super new to AJAX. Thanks

```
function web()
{
if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
    var obj = document.getElementById('content');
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "./nav/web.html");


    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
        XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {

            obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
            }
        }
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
    }
}

function prices()
{
if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
    var obj = document.getElementById('content');
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "./nav/prices.html");


    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
        XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {

            obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
            }
        }
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
    }
}

function clientList()
{
if(XMLHttpRequestObject) {
    var obj = document.getElementById('content');
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "./nav/clientlist.html");


    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
        XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {

            obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
            }
        }
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: use [jquery](http://jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, instead of having a function to each process, have built in a "template" that will hold every request, and then pass a variable to use like

```
switch(b) { case "web" : XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "./nav/web.html"); break; case "prices" : XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "./nav/prices.html");
```

here is a sample

```
function dameloPapa(a,b,c) {
if (a=="")
  {
  document.getElementById(c).innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(c).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
switch(b){
case "web" : XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "./nav/web.html?id"+a); break;
//etc...
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

This way you only call in your code using JavaScript (onclick, onchange, etc) dameloPapa('variable','op','div_id'); and show results on

I optimized one like this to be call upon anytime that I want, I mix a lot this with PHP, MySQL and works like a charm, hope this helps!

Comment: This really seems like a less-than-optimal solution to the OP's problem. Especially the string-switch dispatched lookups...

Comment: It can be done in many may ways, using jquery, dojo, etc ajax built-in, now for what he ask, it's very simply and clean, I use this for many of my scripts and works very well

Comment: not arguing that it works, arguing that time invested building functions in that style could be better spent on more creative pursuits.